# How to change Range in Countif formula based on list in Column A

Tags: worksheet-function, countif

So I have a worksheet that has 2 columns

```
column A(name)(Cell A1)  - Column B(how many resets)(Cell B1)

Sheet1(Cell A2)    YES(Cell B2)
Sheet2(Cell A3)    YES(Cell B2)
Sheet3(Cell A4)    YES(Cell B4)
```

My question is: how to change Range in `Countif` formula based on list in Column A

```
=COUNTIF('Sheet1'!G:G,"Yes")
```

Sheet 1 is the range.

As all I want to do is pull down on the formula and then it populates the correct range from the list in cell A.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: so you want to change the sheet name as it is dragged down?

Comment: Yes, the one on the formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDIRECT()

INDIRECT makes a valid range reference from a string.

So we need to make a string.  We can use `&` to concatenate the string:

```
"'" & A2 & "'!G:G"
```

This will return:

```
'Sheet1'!G:G
'Sheet2'!G:G
'Sheet3'!G:G
```

As it is dragged down.

So we just need to wrap the above formula in INDIRECT to return an actual range reference:

```
INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!G:G")
```

This will now return a valid range reference, we just need to add it into the COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & A2 & "'!G:G"),"Yes")
```

Comment: You are a legend! I have bene looking at Indirects, but wasn't sure how to incorporate it in the formula. You have you dumbed it down enough so anyone can understand!